# TS compiler error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Status'

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, code-generation, graphql-js

I am defining the following `Query` object:

```
export const Query = {

  // Feed
  feed(parent, args, ctx: Context, info) {
    const { filter, skip, first, orderBy } = args
    const where = filter
      ? {
          AND: [
            { status: 'ACTIVE' },
            {
              OR: [
                { name_contains: filter },
                { description_contains: filter }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      : { status: 'ACTIVE' }

    return ctx.db.query.listings({ where, skip, first, orderBy }, info)
  },
  // ...
}
```

The TS compiler complains about the `status: 'ACTIVE'` part:

```
[ts]
Argument of type '{ where: { AND: ({ status: string; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: ({ name_contains: any; description_c...' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ where?: ListingWhereInput; orderBy?: ListingOrderByInput; skip?: number; after?: string; before...'.
  Types of property 'where' are incompatible.
    Type '{ AND: ({ status: string; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: ({ name_contains: any; description_contains?:...' is not assignable to type 'ListingWhereInput'.
      Type '{ AND: ({ status: string; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: ({ name_contains: any; description_contains?:...' is not assignable to type 'ListingWhereInput'.
        Types of property 'AND' are incompatible.
          Type '({ status: string; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: ({ name_contains: any; description_contains?: undefi...' is not assignable to type 'ListingWhereInput | ListingWhereInput[]'.
            Type '({ status: string; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: ({ name_contains: any; description_contains?: undefi...' is not assignable to type 'ListingWhereInput[]'.
              Type '{ status: string; OR?: undefined; } | { OR: ({ name_contains: any; description_contains?: undefin...' is not assignable to type 'ListingWhereInput'.
                Type '{ status: string; OR?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ListingWhereInput'.
                  Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Status'.
```

Note that the `Status` type is auto-generated based on a `enum` in GraphQL SDL which looks as follows:

```
enum Status {
  ACTIVE
  EXPIRED
  SOLD
  DELETED
}
```

The generated TS definition looks as follows:

```
export type Status = 
  'ACTIVE' |
  'EXPIRED' |
  'SOLD' |
  'DELETED'
```

I don't understand why the TS compiler complains about the `status: 'ACTIVE'` part. According to my understanding, this is should work as `status` can only be either of the four defined string values?!

**More info**:

In case it helps, here are the generated type definitions of the other involved types (everything is generated based on GraphQL SDL):

```
export type Query = {
  listings: (args: { where?: ListingWhereInput, orderBy?: ListingOrderByInput, skip?: Int, after?: String, before?: String, first?: Int, last?: Int }, info?: GraphQLResolveInfo | string) => Promise<Listing[]>
  // ... other fields
}

export interface ListingWhereInput {
  AND?: ListingWhereInput[] | ListingWhereInput
  OR?: ListingWhereInput[] | ListingWhereInput
  id?: ID_Input
  id_not?: ID_Input
  id_in?: ID_Input[] | ID_Input
  id_not_in?: ID_Input[] | ID_Input
  id_lt?: ID_Input
  id_lte?: ID_Input
  id_gt?: ID_Input
  id_gte?: ID_Input
  id_contains?: ID_Input
  id_not_contains?: ID_Input
  id_starts_with?: ID_Input
  id_not_starts_with?: ID_Input
  id_ends_with?: ID_Input
  id_not_ends_with?: ID_Input
  name?: String
  name_not?: String
  name_in?: String[] | String
  name_not_in?: String[] | String
  name_lt?: String
  name_lte?: String
  name_gt?: String
  name_gte?: String
  name_contains?: String
  name_not_contains?: String
  name_starts_with?: String
  name_not_starts_with?: String
  name_ends_with?: String
  name_not_ends_with?: String
  description?: String
  description_not?: String
  description_in?: String[] | String
  description_not_in?: String[] | String
  description_lt?: String
  description_lte?: String
  description_gt?: String
  description_gte?: String
  description_contains?: String
  description_not_contains?: String
  description_starts_with?: String
  description_not_starts_with?: String
  description_ends_with?: String
  description_not_ends_with?: String
  price?: Int
  price_not?: Int
  price_in?: Int[] | Int
  price_not_in?: Int[] | Int
  price_lt?: Int
  price_lte?: Int
  price_gt?: Int
  price_gte?: Int
  location?: String
  location_not?: String
  location_in?: String[] | String
  location_not_in?: String[] | String
  location_lt?: String
  location_lte?: String
  location_gt?: String
  location_gte?: String
  location_contains?: String
  location_not_contains?: String
  location_starts_with?: String
  location_not_starts_with?: String
  location_ends_with?: String
  location_not_ends_with?: String
  condition?: Condition
  condition_not?: Condition
  condition_in?: Condition[] | Condition
  condition_not_in?: Condition[] | Condition
  status?: Status
  status_not?: Status
  status_in?: Status[] | Status
  status_not_in?: Status[] | Status
  expiredAt?: DateTime
  expiredAt_not?: DateTime
  expiredAt_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  expiredAt_not_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  expiredAt_lt?: DateTime
  expiredAt_lte?: DateTime
  expiredAt_gt?: DateTime
  expiredAt_gte?: DateTime
  soldAt?: DateTime
  soldAt_not?: DateTime
  soldAt_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  soldAt_not_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  soldAt_lt?: DateTime
  soldAt_lte?: DateTime
  soldAt_gt?: DateTime
  soldAt_gte?: DateTime
  deletedAt?: DateTime
  deletedAt_not?: DateTime
  deletedAt_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  deletedAt_not_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  deletedAt_lt?: DateTime
  deletedAt_lte?: DateTime
  deletedAt_gt?: DateTime
  deletedAt_gte?: DateTime
  createdAt?: DateTime
  createdAt_not?: DateTime
  createdAt_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  createdAt_not_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  createdAt_lt?: DateTime
  createdAt_lte?: DateTime
  createdAt_gt?: DateTime
  createdAt_gte?: DateTime
  updatedAt?: DateTime
  updatedAt_not?: DateTime
  updatedAt_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  updatedAt_not_in?: DateTime[] | DateTime
  updatedAt_lt?: DateTime
  updatedAt_lte?: DateTime
  updatedAt_gt?: DateTime
  updatedAt_gte?: DateTime
  seller?: UserWhereInput
  likes_every?: ListingLikeWhereInput
  likes_some?: ListingLikeWhereInput
  likes_none?: ListingLikeWhereInput
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is typescript will not infer string literal types for object literal properties, so the `status` in will be typed as `string` not `'ACTIVE'`

You could specify the type for `where` explicitly:

```
const where:ListingWhereInput  = ..
```

Or you can use a type assertion for force the property to be of the string literal type

```
{ status: 'ACTIVE' as  'ACTIVE'}
```